# Double integral intervals.

Tags: integration

I just started with double integrals and I have problems finding integrals intervals.

For example i have to solve this :
$$\int\int_D (x+6y) {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y=$$
where the domain D is given as follows: D: $y=x, y=5x, x=1$

what my integrals points should be:
$$\int_?^?\int_?^? (x+6y) {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y=$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first plot $y=x, y=2x, x=1$ in your graph, it will be a triangle. Set up your limits such that $\iint dy dx  = \mathrm{Area \, of \, region}$ here this case, triangle.

$$\int_0^1 (5x - x)\, dx = \int_0^{1} \int_x^{5x} \dots dy dx $$

Put your integrand function into $\dots$ and evaluate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just wondering if i can't find the points without plotting?

Comment: @user137209 yes you can find it without plotting. Just solve $y=x$ and $y=5x$, you will get $(0,0)$.

Comment: After i get (0,0) how do i know that my dx integral is from 0 to 1? Sorry for bothering you with my questions.

Comment: @user137209 as I explained above, just set up your limits such that, it will give area of the region when you integrate $1$ instead of $f(x)$.

Comment: Oh, i get it!. Thank you very much.

Comment: I see a typo.. we need to plot $y=x$ and $y=5x$... since this is a type 1 graph, we need to draw a vertical line to see which graph is the lowest. The lowest graph is $f(a)$ and the highest graph is $f(b)$.